# Is it possible to modify ng-content from within a component/directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Is it possible to append to `<ng-content>` from within a component or directive?

I am currently attempting to set up a pipeline that allows for a directive to append a text node to the beginning of the transcluded content.

```html
<some-component appendContent="text to append">
    <div class="initial-content">test</div>
</some-component>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>  
    `
})
export class SomeComponent {
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[appendContent]'
})
export class AppendContentDirective {
    @Input('appendContent') content: string;
}
```

I know that `ContentChildren` allows me to query for things within `ng-content`, but I could not find any information on a way to append elements to give the following result.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="initial-content">test</div>
    <div class="appended-content">text to append</div>
</div>
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjquyz

You'll notice that the stackblitz above instead generates:

```html
<div class="appended-content">text to append</div>z
<div class="container">
    <div class="initial-content">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To append a div, you can use rendered2 (not insertAdjacentElement). renderer.appendChild required an element ref, not use this.elementRef.nativeElement else this.elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild

```
ngOnInit() {
    const contentElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    contentElement.classList.add('appended-content');
    contentElement.textContent = this.content;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement.lastChild,contentElement)
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsk7nt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fappend-content.directive.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the issue. Renderers appendChild largely does the same thing but more safely (nice catch though). The firstChild still grabs the first element within the host instead of the first transcluded element.

Comment: @BohrHew, I just updated the stackblit to add the initial-class to the content. it's look like `<div class="container"><div _ngcontent-mov-c2="" class="initial-content">test</div><div _ngcontent-mov-c2="" class="appended-content">text to append</div></div>`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I was trying to achieve. I'm not simply attempting to get the desired output (which is what you are achieving by calling first child). I'm trying to append it to `ng-content`.
Simply adding another container wrapper would break your solution.

Comment: ::sorry:: what about use lastChild instead?

Comment: Manipulating `this.elementRef.nativeElement` will not modify `ng-content`. I know `@ContentChild` allows you to query things within `ng-content`, but doesn't allow you to query with wildcards (at least I couldn't find out how).

Comment: @BohrHew, I surrender, using lastChild don't work? any example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmdkva The same case as before with the second wrapping div

Comment: your container.component.html is `<div class="container"><div class="container"><ng-content></ng-content></div></div>` the append test is after the inner `<div class="container">`. I thoung that your container.component.html was `<div class="container"><ng-content></ng-content></div>` -only one div- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsk7nt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainer.component.ts

Comment: I'm trying to modify `ng-content` without relying on the structure of the surrounding component. Having one or two wrapping divs should be irrelevant and the structure could be anything with `ng-content` being in any location within the component.